# android difference between imageview and linear layout for showing image

Tags: android, android-imageview

i have some image (either resource image or bitmap image)
what is the major difference between showing them in `ImageView` or set them as background in `LinearLayout`.
any difference in `Quality` or `Memory usage` ?

Comment: Image View's src property kept the picture aspect ratio bydefault. LinearLayout does not kept.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the major difference between showing them in ImageView or set
>   them as background in LinearLayout.

When you set a background to a layout.It may re-size and change the shape of the image.So it may change your expected output view.

ImageView is specially designed for setting images and it has extra features like `android:scaleType`, you can set the exact image and use function like `crop`.

> any difference in Quality or Memory usage

`Image view` is a view and it will reduce the computation of loading the `layout` each time while using a layout for this porpose.